# Проблема с циклической переадресацией

Tags: php

Нужно сделать так, чтобы сайт был доступен только с поисковиков, то есть по прямой ссылке запретить вход на сайт. Мне дали вот такой код:

```
// checking visitor's user agent
$useragent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

$refUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

function redirect($url, $permanent = true)
{
    if (headers_sent() === false)
    {
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, ($permanent === true) ? 301 : 302);
    }

    exit();
}

if (strpos($useragent, "googlebot") !== false || strpos($useragent, "google") !== false || strpos($useragent, "yandex") !== false || strpos($useragent, "mail.ru") !== false || strpos($refUrl, "google") !== false || strpos($refUrl, "yandex") !== false || strpos($refUrl, "mail.ru") !== false)
        {
         // redirect goes here for normal people
         redirect( 'https://домен', true);

        }
else {
   // redirect on ERROR page goes here
   redirect( 'https://домен', true);
}
```

Разобрался куда вставить, вставил. При входе на сайт с поисковика мне пишет: «обнаружена циклическая переадресация». Что я не так сделал?

Answer (score 0):

Так не надо делать. Если то, что видит пользователь, отличается от того, что видит Google, будут санкции.

Comment: ну а все же, сайт не просто о картинах и живописи, а партнерка казино